# Flutter Unknown camera ID 0

Tags: flutter, camera

With the last version of [flutter camera plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera), a user meet this error and has a dark screen :

> CameraException(error, supportsCameraApi:2340: Unknown camera ID 0)

My code :

```
final List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      if(cameras.isNotEmpty) selectedCamera = cameras.first;
```

He is using Android 11 with KT107 device model